# Composer install VS composer install --dev

Tags: composer-php

Is there any differences between "composer install" and "composer install --dev"?

I ran these two commands and get the same packages installed.

Answer (score -1):

As you can read in the [documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install-i), leaving it out and using `--dev` performs the same action:

> --dev: Install packages listed in `require-dev` (this is the default behavior).